# Typescript function return type based on argument

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to have a dynamic return type for the `showTest` function based on the definition of the `TestType`?

If the argument is `TestEnum.ONE`, then the return type would be `boolean`, or in the case is `TestEnum.TWO`, then the return type would be `string`.

```
enum TestEnum {
  ONE= 'one',
  TWO= 'two'
}

type TestType = {
  [TestEnum.ONE]: boolean;
  [TestEnum.TWO]: number
}

const someObject = {
  [TestEnum.ONE]: true,
  [TestEnum.TWO]: 123
}

const showTest = (value: TestEnum) => {
  const result = someObject[value];
  if (typeof result === 'undefined') {
    throw new Error(`Unable to find ${value} in object`);
  }
  return result;
};

showTest(TestEnum.ONE) // return true and return type is boolean
showTest(TestEnum.TWO) // return 123 and return type is number
```

Comment: What is `someObject`?

Comment: I suppose `someObject` matches the type `TestType`?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/NlxD5N) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: `someObject` and `flag` seem to be in error here.  Presumably the answer here will be "make `showTest` generic" but you should probably go through the effort of getting a reproducible example.  That example should also show what you mean about the return type, by calling `showTest` and demonstrating that it returns `boolean | number` instead of the desired `number` or `boolean` (so `showTest(TestEnum.TWO).toFixed(2)` will be a compiler error but it shouldn't be).  Good example code leads to good answers.

Comment: @jcalz just updated, thanks for the feedback

Comment: Your solution is fine but you should post it as an answer and not as an edit to the question.

Comment: @jcalz thanks again for the feedback 

Answer (score 0):

You can overload your function, so it would accept `TestEnum` and return different values depending on actual value of `value`.

```js
enum TestEnum {
  ONE= 'one',
  TWO= 'two'
}

function showTest(value: TestEnum.ONE): boolean;
function showTest(value: TestEnum.TWO): string;
function showTest(value: TestEnum): boolean | string {
    if (value === TestEnum.ONE) return true;
    else if (value === TestEnum.TWO) return "not one";
    throw new Error('should never happen');
}

let shouldBeBoolean = showTest(TestEnum.ONE);
let shouldBeString = showTest(TestEnum.TWO);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution: [TS Playground link here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/KYOwrgtgBAKsDOAXAouaBvAsAKClA8gHLIC8UA5APYjDkA0OeMA6vmeYgO6Xk4C%20OHIgCeAB2CwEiGGIlksuKAG04SVJAB0RZAF0AXFABGlSgBtgAQxABuRstUo0Glvn1Q0h4ACd%20g7AGNqJCh4SghgfEMAK2B-RCh5OxUpdQgtYjdELzBgBkVktScXNwBGACYAZl9sHECQYPgAC0pOBwSoAB4AaShgAA9EUAATeCgAa2BhSgAzSSQZcQA%20AAoANwtTHIMugEoDBwXgJS6dBMWoBTw64K8EMFN4slDwyJi4pXXN4B1bRQBLWbLETiGZQW7we6PEjsMAgIbAaZ-GhDcg7C52PCIRpeFruYCcKDILw4rzLAAGAFUQBZDOYoIhKFBEXCoAASdCfHJ8KBIqCUaKxRBkna-PACRS3RBgLwgMF3B6-Pi-WpBeLGMwANQ2OXaTRaDmWDlS6WQaIA9Ga5VKZfTshIrEMrdLZcCJH9RurzFYVfV4h5vFqvrrmq0pIaUkVWObLZLnVByhUoA6nTbXTzRv6fDUAkEzMANKZKABzZaewM5Oj02Sgsva4A7H2hcwF4vLTPl3JVkGzdt1nZAA)

```
enum TestEnum {
  ONE= 'one',
  TWO= 'two'
}

type TestType = {
  [TestEnum.ONE]: boolean;
  [TestEnum.TWO]: number
}

const someObject = {
  [TestEnum.ONE]: true,
  [TestEnum.TWO]: 123
}

const showTest = <K extends keyof TestType>(value: K): TestType[K] => {
  const result = someObject[value];
  if (typeof result === 'undefined') {
    throw new Error(`Unable to find ${value} in object`);
  }
  return result;
};

const boolValue = showTest(TestEnum.ONE) // return true and return type is boolean
const numberValue = showTest(TestEnum.TWO) // return 123 and return type is number
```